# How to parse a word document in salesforce?

Tags: parsing, ms-word, salesforce

Can some one suggest me on how to parse a word document that is placed as an attachment to an attachment to an object in salesforce. Say i have a word doc attachment , I parse and read the doc and then fill the custom abject field in salesforce.

Just like read resume and then create candidate object with data that is read from the document.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if this document is a .docx file then it is an archive. Theoretically you can extract xml file with your document part, parse it, and save back. But to be honest Apex is surely not meant for such manipultiions. Also there are several suits available at AppExchange, that offer functionality to work with office files.